# Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.search:mapbox-search-android

Tags: android, mapbox-android

I am using this com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.7.0 mapbox sdk version in android studio, and i want to use mapbox autofill search api.
For searching sdk i am using

implementation "com.mapbox.search:mapbox-search-android-native:1.0.0-rc.7"
this dependency but it always show

"Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.search:mapbox-search-android-native:1.0.0-rc.7"
How to fix ?